# Continuity and direct substitution

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I understand completely the intuition of recognizing when a function is continuous, and I understand that I can prove continuity of a function $f(x)$ by showing that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches a is equal to $f(a)$... But so far, I haven't found an explanation of ***why*** the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches a is equal to $f(a)$, when it is. Can anybody provide an explanation that doesn't invoke continuity or intuition? If it must involve continuity, can you redefine continuity without using the limit definition? I'm dealing with single variable functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks,
Doodle

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of understanding a definition.  Something is continuous exactly when the limit of $f(x)$ approaches $f(a)$ when $x$ approaches $a$.

Let us define a new term.  Let's call a function starable when that function is equal to 0 for all negative values of $x$ and 8 for all non-negative values of $x$.  We could look at a function and determine whether or not it was starable.  However, one would not ask why the function is starable.

I may have missed your misunderstanding.  Perhaps it's that you'd like to understand continuity better.  In that case, it benefits us to understand continuity in terms of the definition of the limit.

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a point $a$ means that for all values of $\epsilon>0$, there exists an open interval around $a$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ in the interval.  This is basically just the rigid definition of the limit applied to continuity.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I suppose my question really should have been: how does one prove that the limit of a function actually is some particular number, but the rigid definition of limits answer that.